# a sent message for an unknown number without me sending it

Tags: attacks

there is a message sent from my iPhone to an international number.
but i didn't send it and it doesn't appear in my message history.
is this possible?
how can it happen?

Comment: Did you recognize that on your mobile phone's bill? That could be the iMessage activation text; in Europe, it goes to Belgium, I think. Try google on the number and see if it's one of apple's gateways. They send a text to verify the phone number you register with iMessage when you activate iMessage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

### If your iPhone is not jail broken

There is probably nothing to worry about:

Apple send themselves a registration text to verify your iMessage registration (and says so in the text when activating iMessage).

The destination gateways receiving the texts are international, those for Europe are in Belgium, if I recall that correctly.

Just google the number and see if apple comes up as a result.

### If your phone is jail broken

You might been "lucky" with some form of malware.

In that case, google on the number may still help and keeping an eye on the running processes and connections might be useful to find out more.